# How to include an array in cell of a tabular environment

Tags: tables, arrays

For an equation that has an array we use `\\` for new row as well, and `\newline` didn't work, and this is understood by the tabular environment as a new row! Would appreciate all the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be good if you would show the code of this equation, so we can help to fix it.

Comment: \begin{tabular}{p{10em }p{4em }}

$\mathbf{P} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 - \alpha & \alpha \\beta & 1 - \beta \end{array} \right]$  &

Comment: You can edit your question to add the source code. Please indent it by 4 spaces or use the '101010' button to format it as code.

Comment: Try to wrap the whole `array` inside braces `{ }` and see if it helps.

Comment: An `array` environment should be in math mode, so surround it with `$` signs.

Comment: Did you tried `\tabularnewline`?

Answer (score 3):

With regard to the code snippet you provided in a comment: Yes, this array may be put into a cell of a `tabular` environment, and no, `\newline` is not understood as a new row inside a `p` column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{10em}p{4em}}
A & Bla\newline bla \\
\( \mathbf{P} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 - \alpha & \alpha \\ \beta & 1 - \beta \end{array} \right] \) & D
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For *smaller* (single column) inclusions of an `array`/`tabular`-style object in your table, you may also consider using the the [`makecell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) package in the following way:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    A & B & C \\
    D & \makecell[c]{$E$ \\ F} & G \\
    H & I & J
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{10em }p{4em }} 
  \begin{minipage}{10em} %%
    \begin{math} %%
      \mathbf{P} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} %%
          1 - \alpha & \alpha \\ %%
          \beta & 1 - \beta %%
        \end{array} \right] %%
    \end{math} %%
  \end{minipage} & \it table \\
  \it table & \it table
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the `minipage`? Your code works without it. Also, you should use `\itshape` instead of `\it`.

Comment: `minipage` is my goto for solving these kinds of problems. Good to know it's not absolutely necessary.